# Como lograr que el nombre de la app y página principal sean diferentes

Tags: android

En mi app que estoy desarrollando quisiera colocar el titulo a la pagina principal o de inicio "CONSOLA" y al nombre de mi app "Demosx", pero por mas intentos que hago en modificar el manifest siempre aparece el nombre de mi app y la pagina principal como "CONSOLA", alguien me podria decir como lograr esto, que el nombre de la app y la página inicio sean diferentes.

Aqui esta el fragmento del manifest:

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Demosx"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="CONSOLA"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: En tu pregunta parece que le poner "Consola" a la actividad principal, y parece ser que eso es lo que te aparece. Entonces ¿cuál vendría a ser el problema?

Comment: Necesito que el nombre de mi app sea "Demox"

Comment: @W1ll que sucede cuando mandas a background tu MainActivity, que titulo se muestra?, podrías agregar tu build.gradle?